# API data in Datatable JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, datatables

I'm trying to show all the from an API in a Datatable JS.
My API Structure is like

```
{
  "Success": {
    "Meta": {
      "Id": "124578828",
      "Action": "ItemList",
      "Type": "Item"
    },
    "Body": {
      "TotalItems": 18,
      "Item": [
        {
          "Category": "Clothing",
          "ItemId": 12354,
          "Attributes": {
            "name": "Tee 1",
            "brand": "Brand 2",
            "material_type": "Cotton",
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
          },
          "Skus": [
            {
              "Status": "active",
              "stock": 20,
              "Images": [
                "images/tee1_01.jpg",
                "images/tee1_02.jpg",
                "images/tee1_03.jpg",
                "",
                "",
                "",
                "",
                ""
              ],
              "Sku": "TEE-001233",
              "Url": "#",
              "price": 20,
              "Available": 12
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Trying to show Item **Success.Body.Item[].Attributes.name,Success.Body.Item[].Attributes.brand, Success.Body.Item[].Skus[].Images[0] & Success.Body.Item[].Skus[].price in columns**

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {


         $('#data-table').DataTable({
             "ajax": "GetProducts.json",
             "columns": [{
                     "data": "Success.Body.Item[].Attributes.name"
                 },
                 {
                     "data": "Success.Body.Item[].Attributes.brand"
                 },
                 {
                     "data": "Success.Body.Item[].Skus[].Images[0]"
                 },
                 {
                     "data": "Success.Body.Item[].Skus[].price"
                 }
             ]
         });
     });
 </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can put like this

```
function table() {
fetch(urlApi)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(datos => {
    document.querySelector('#table').innerHTML = `
                    <tr>
                    <th>${ datos.Success.Body.Item[0].Attributes.name}</th>
                    <td>${ datos.Success.Body.Item[0].Attributes.model}</td> 
                    <td>${ datos.Success.Body.Item[0].Skus[0].Images}</td>
                    <td>${ datos.Success.Success.Body.Item[0].Skus[0].price}</td>
                </tr>
             `

  })
```

}

if you save the answer in a variable (For example a) you can get the data like this:

```
a.Success.Body.Item[0].Skus[0].price
```

Comment: This solves the problem with trying to use Item[] - but perhaps you could explain why/how it solves that problem? On the other hand, DataTables has built-in handling for JSON, so there should be no need to resort to DOM manipulation with JavaScript/HTML, in this way.